# ListView won't update

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a listview with a customized ArrayAdapter. When the in the ArrayAdapter has changed the gui is supposed to update. However, when it's supposed to update, it won't unless you press a key on the emulator. The clickable rows are not clickable either unless i have clicked on an arbitrary button on the emulator. 
The underlying data for the listview is changed somewhere else and then notifying the observer (the listview in this case)

```
public void update(java.util.Observable arg0, Object arg1) 
    {
        Log.e("Supposed","to update");
        ad.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Ad is the arrayadapter                         
    }
```

The data is presented properly after the magic touch on the buttons. But why?
Any thoughts?
When i inspect the ArrayAdapter's items-reference it shows the updated values, but the gui wont.
Plz help

edit:

```
private class MustAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> 
    {
        public MustAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> items)
        {
            super(context,textViewResourceId,items);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                }

                Item o = items.get(position);
                if (o != null) {

                        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1); 
                        TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                        ImageView iv= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
                        ImageView ib = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.OnOffButt);
                        if (ib != null) {
                            ib.setTag(position);
                            if (((Ventilation)o).enabled ==0 ) {
                                ib.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_input_delete);
                            }
                            else
                                ib.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
                            ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                int index=((Integer)arg0.getTag()).intValue();
                                Ventilation v= (Ventilation)items.get(index);
                                v.enabled=v.enabled != 0 ? 0 : 1;
                                //ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                DU.toggle(v);


                            }
                        });
                        }

                        if (iv !=null){
                            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.fan);
                        }
                        if (tt != null) {
                              tt.setText(""+((Ventilation)o).actual);                            }
                        if(bt != null){
                              bt.setText(""+((Ventilation)o).setPoint);
                        }
                }
                return v;
        }
```

Even when i use arrayadapter.add(item) i have to press somewhere else for it to reload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the thing is that no thread but the gui thread can update the gui thread.
So what I did was to declare a Handler in the onCreate event.

```
h= new Handler(){
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg)
                {
                    switch (msg.what)
                    {
                    case 0:
                        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            };
```

and in my `public void update(java.util.Observable arg0, Object arg1)`

I put

```
Message ms= new Message();
        ms.what=0;
        h.sendMessage(ms);
```

Thats it! Hope this one comes handy for someone.

Answer (score 0):

> When the in the ArrayAdapter has
>   changed the gui is supposed to update.

If will, if you change the `ArrayAdapter`'s data via `add()`, `insert()`, or `remove()`. If you change the data some other way, `ArrayAdapter` will not know about the change.

Comment: Even arrayadapter.add(Item) needs an press at any button to respond to changes.

Comment: @Raul: no, it does not. See http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Threads/Asyncer/ and http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/04-ListView/

Comment: Guess my emulator does not work then. I'll try on ubuntu in a few days